# AddRange missing final element in List?

Tags: c#, linq

In a program I'm creating in C#, I have a `List<XElement>` and a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`. Initially, when I load the program, I have a bit of code like so:

```
Results.AddRange(steps.Select(x => new Tuple<string, string>(x.Attribute("ExcelCell").Value, string.Empty)));
```

This appears to work at first, but upon checking it, there are 53 elements in the first list and 52 in the second. I noticed this originally when I received an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. For whatever reason, it seems to be missing the final element in the list. Why is this?

Comment: I don't see any reason why that should happen.  Try breaking it out into two statements.  `var selectedSteps = steps.Select(...).ToList();` and then `Results.AddRange(selectedSteps);` and debug it line by line to see if it's a problem with the select or something else.

Comment: So you're saying that `steps` had `53` elements, but `Results` only ended up with `52`?

Comment: What is the first list and the second list?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Show me the code. I cannot believe it.

Comment: Show more code. If `Results` was not empty but had a `Count` of 1 before the `AddRange`, and if `steps` has 52 elements, then after the addition `Results` will have 1+52, or 53, elements.